# Rvest How to avoid the Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404 R

Tags: r, rvest

I'd like to take some informations from a list of website.
I have a list of urls, but there are some that doesn't work/exesist.

The Error is:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404 R

```
library(Rvest)
url_web<-(c("https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roma",
        "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milano",
        "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoli",
        "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torinoooo", # for example this is an error
        "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palermo",
        "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venezia"))
```

I write this code for my target.

I tried to use `try`, but doesn't work.

I tried to use an `ifelse(url.exists(url_web)==TRUE,Cont<-read_html(url_web), NA )` into the `for`, but doesn't work.

```
for (i in 1:length(url_web)){
      Cont<-read_html(i)
      Dist_1<-html_nodes(Cont, ".firstHeading") %>% 
      html_text()
      print(Dist_1)
    }
```

The question is: How I can jump the url where I can't link or where is writes wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `try` should do the trick

```
parsed_pages <- replicate(list(), n = length(url_web))
for (k in seq_along(url_web)) parsed_pages[[k]] <- try(xml2::read_html(url_web[k]), silent = TRUE)
```

The `silent = TRUE` argument means any error will be disregarded. By default, `silent = FALSE` which makes `try` report the errors. Note that even if `silent = FALSE` the code works (the reported errors might make it look as thought it didn't).

Here we can test the above code

```
for (k in seq_along(url_web)) print(class(parsed_pages[[k]]))
# [1] "xml_document" "xml_node"    
# [1] "xml_document" "xml_node"    
# [1] "xml_document" "xml_node"    
# [1] "try-error"
# [1] "xml_document" "xml_node"    
# [1] "xml_document" "xml_node"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer.
I'm trying to implement it, but I'm finding some trouble. 
I let you know soon.

Comment: The problem was in my urls and not in your code.
Thank you again.  :)